# Working with Two-Dimensional Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working with a two-dimensional array with 9 and 9 elements, grid[9][9], i need to check if specific elements are equal and if so to flag the 1st array for the second array.

```
bool gridWon(int n){
    if ( grid[n][0] != 0 && grid[n][0] == grid[n][1] && grid[n][0] == grid[n][2]){
        return true;
    } else if ( grid[n][3] != 0 && grid[n][3] == grid[n][4] && grid[n][5] == grid[n][3]){
        return true;
    } else if ( grid[n][6] != 0 && grid[n][6] == grid[n][7] && grid[n][8] == grid[n][6]){
        return true;
    } else if ( grid[n][0] != 0 && grid[n][0] == grid[n][4] && grid[n][8] == grid[n][0]){
        return true;
    } else if ( grid[n][2] != 0 && grid[n][2] == grid[n][4] && grid[n][6] == grid[n][2]){
        return true;
    } else if ( grid[n][0] != 0 && grid[n][0] == grid[n][3] && grid[n][6] == grid[n][0]){
        return true;
    } else if ( grid[n][1] != 0 && grid[n][1] == grid[n][4] && grid[n][7] == grid[n][1]){
        return true;
    } else if ( grid[n][2] != 0 && grid[n][2] == grid[n][5] && grid[n][8] == grid[n][2]){
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

How can I write this more elegant and how can I flag the grid[n][] in order to compare them later?

example:

> if grid[1][] returns true then I need to know later to compare if grid[1][] == grid[2][] == true

Comment: Use a loop maybe?

Comment: Write a function that takes the array indexes, so you can do `if (check_cells(grid[n], 3, 4, 5))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can it be better to return the result of a logical operation:

```
bool gridWon(int n){
 return (grid[n][0] != 0 && grid[n][0] == grid[n][1] && grid[n][0] == grid[n][2]) ||
  (grid[n][3] != 0 && grid[n][3] == grid[n][4] && grid[n][5] == grid[n][3]) ||
  (grid[n][6] != 0 && grid[n][6] == grid[n][7] && grid[n][8] == grid[n][6]) ||
  (grid[n][0] != 0 && grid[n][0] == grid[n][4] && grid[n][8] == grid[n][0]) ||
  (grid[n][2] != 0 && grid[n][2] == grid[n][4] && grid[n][6] == grid[n][2]) ||
  (grid[n][0] != 0 && grid[n][0] == grid[n][3] && grid[n][6] == grid[n][0]) ||
  (grid[n][1] != 0 && grid[n][1] == grid[n][4] && grid[n][7] == grid[n][1]) ||
  (grid[n][2] != 0 && grid[n][2] == grid[n][5] && grid[n][8] == grid[n][2]);
}
```